# How to I use a longtabu inside \newenvironment?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, tabu, longtabu

I have the following newenvironment defined using tabularx

```
\newenvironment{factlist}{%
    \newdimen\unbaseline
    \unbaseline=\dimexpr-\baselinestretch\baselineskip\relax
    \renewcommand\item[2]{%
    \textsc{##1} & {\raggedright ##2\smallskip\\}\\[\unbaseline]}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{rX}}
    {\endtabularx}
```

I use it as follows:

```
\begin{factlist}
\item{A}{aaaa}
\item{B}{bbbb}
...
\item{Z}{zzzz}
\end{factlist}
```

Trouble is, the "factlist" does not split across pages. I believe this is because tabularx does not fit across pages.

I figured that "longtabu" from the "tabu" package has the same syntax as tabularx. However, I am not able to replace \tabularx and \endtabularx with \begin{longtabu} and \end{longtabu} in newenvironment. It throws a Runaway argument exception.

I am new to Latex. It would be nice if you could help me getting this code to work.

I am open to other methods as well, since all I want to do is BE ABLE TO SPLIT THE "FACTLIST" ACROSS PAGES!

Comment: In any case, `\newdimen` should be outside the environment. You *declare* a dimen, and then set it every time with the environment. But there's no reason to (in fact you can't) declare a new dimen everytime you use the environment.

Answer (score 2):

It is almost always better to set these things as a list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{factlist}{%
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{\textsc{\Alph{enumi}}}}
{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}

\begin{factlist}
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\item One two three four five.
\end{factlist}

\end{document}
```

the exact list parameters can be tuned to the exact requirements,

Comment: I've used `\textsc` as in the question but it's an almost unnoticable font change on capital letters.

Comment: The question is not about \textsc at all. This tex script is taken from a template for a resume. And using \textsc is relevant in that context. Also, your reply isn't exactly what I was looking for. I am aware that I can use \item, but I need a table to ensure proper alignment, etc in the resume.

Comment: @P.C. yes that's why I relegated the `\textsc` to a comment. It would be very surprising if you can not get the alignment that you need using a list based layout. But it's your document and only you know the requirements that you have,